# Route to React component from Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I've got an express backend and want to send the user a react component when a specific route is requested from the server. How can I do this?
I've also got react-router setup on the frontend, but I'm unable to redirect to a react route when an express route is requested...

Answer (score 0):

use axios.

```
let result = await axios.get("url<localhost>/route<api route of express>");
```

Comment: URL would be your http://localhost:port if you are running the express app on the local machine. API route would be the one that you provided in the router file. 
The sample URL would be like this:  http://localhost:3000/user/getDetails

Comment: I need to route to a react component from the express backend, not to an api route on the backend from the react frontend.